# Iterate over a dataset that was populated with READ-XML without like columns for parent-child relationship?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm currently on Openedge 10.1c. I'm using READ-XML to populate a dataset. I can't change the source XML and was was wondering how you would iterate over the dataset when there isn't a parent child relationship unique keys to use in my join.

I'll include sample XML and the display loop when I get to my desk.

In the meantime it's something like this...

```
<data>
  <fulfillments>
    <field1>field1</field1>
    <field2>field2</field2>
    <field3>field3</field3>
    <customer>
      <name>test</name>
    </customer>
  </fulfillments>
  <fulfillments>
    <field1>field11</field1>
    <field2>field22</field2>
    <field3>field33</field3>
    <customer>
      <name>test2</name>
    </customer>
  </fulfillments>
</data>
```

After I use read XML I get all the data but trying to iterate over it I don't know how to display customer in to each fulfillment. Instead it will just show all customers for each fulfillment.

Sample Code reading and displaying the dataset...

```
PROCEDURE _read_xml:
    DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER DATASET-HANDLE idshndl.
    DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER ifileloc  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE OUTPUT       PARAMETER oreturn   AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.

    DEFINE VARIABLE cSourceType             AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cReadMode               AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE lOverrideDefaultMapping AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cFile                   AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cEncoding               AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cSchemaLocation         AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cFieldTypeMapping       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cVerifySchemaMode       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

    IF SEARCH(ifileloc) <> ? THEN
    DO:
        ASSIGN
            cSourceType = "file"
            cFile = ifileloc
            cReadMode = "empty"
            cSchemaLocation = ?
            lOverrideDefaultMapping = ?
            cFieldTypeMapping = ?
            cVerifySchemaMode = ?.

        oreturn = idshndl:READ-XML(cSourceType,
                                   cFile,
                                   cReadMode,
                                   cSchemaLocation,
                                   lOverrideDefaultMapping,
                                   cFieldTypeMapping,
                                   cVerifySchemaMode).
    END.
    ELSE
    DO:
        oreturn = FALSE.
    END.

END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE _fulfillment_display_data:
    DISPLAY "DATA".
    FOR EACH tt_biz_fulfillments NO-LOCK,
        EACH tt_biz_ship_to:
            DISPLAY "FULFILLMENTS".
            DISPLAY tt_biz_fulfillments WITH SIDE-LABELS.        
            DISPLAY tt_biz_ship_to WITH SIDE-LABELS. 
    END.
END PROCEDURE.
```

Sample XML...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <fulfillments>
      <shipping_method>AIM - Direct</shipping_method>
      <picker_id />
      <sales_order_id>234722</sales_order_id>
      <packaging_id>1</packaging_id>
      <scheduled_delivery_date>07/01/2016</scheduled_delivery_date>
      <net_weight>225</net_weight>
      <shipper_name>TEST</shipper_name>
      <external_note>Test Note</external_note>
      <packaging_type>box</packaging_type>
      <bill_to>sender</bill_to>
      <shipping_cost />
      <fulfillment_id>12345</fulfillment_id>
      <ship_to>
         <city>Pittsburgh</city>
         <name>Bizowie</name>
         <zip>15219</zip>
         <is_residential>0</is_residential>
         <company />
         <address>429 Fourth Avenue Suite 1206</address>
         <phone_extension />
         <contact_id>8</contact_id>
         <phone />
         <state>PA</state>
         <country />
         <email />
      </ship_to>
      <location_id>1</location_id>
      <parent_fulfillment_id />
      <location_name>201 - PA</location_name>
      <manifest_number />
      <picker_name />
      <scheduled_pick_date />
      <pick_timestamp />
      <delivery_timestamp />
      <packaging_weight>0.150000</packaging_weight>
      <insured_value />
      <bill_to_zip />
      <internal_note>test note internal</internal_note>
      <bill_to_account />
      <status>shipped</status>
      <dock_number />
      <route_id>1</route_id>
      <delivery_latitude />
      <shipper_id>1</shipper_id>
      <scheduled_ship_date>06/29/2016</scheduled_ship_date>
      <acceptance_timestamp />
      <shipping_carrier />
      <packaging_height>4.0000</packaging_height>
      <packaging_length>4.0000</packaging_length>
      <gross_weight>225.15</gross_weight>
      <packaging_width>4.0000</packaging_width>
      <delivery_longitude />
      <delivery_signer_location />
      <packing_layer />
      <truck_number />
      <route_name />
      <flag_message />
      <delivery_signer_name />
      <tracking_number />
      <packing_row />
      <ship_timestamp>06/09/2016 07:15:15 AM</ship_timestamp>
   </fulfillments>
   <fulfillments>
      <shipping_method>TEST</shipping_method>
      <picker_id />
      <sales_order_id>234722</sales_order_id>
      <packaging_id>1</packaging_id>
      <scheduled_delivery_date>08/05/2016</scheduled_delivery_date>
      <net_weight>440</net_weight>
      <shipper_name>BLAH</shipper_name>
      <external_note>TESTING</external_note>
      <packaging_type>box</packaging_type>
      <bill_to>sender</bill_to>
      <shipping_cost />
      <fulfillment_id>12346</fulfillment_id>
      <ship_to>
         <city>Wyoming</city>
         <name />
         <zip>18644</zip>
         <is_residential />
         <company>Walmart</company>
         <address>10 Moosic St</address>
         <phone_extension />
         <contact_id>1226058</contact_id>
         <phone />
         <state>PA</state>
         <country />
         <email />
      </ship_to>
      <location_id>1</location_id>
      <parent_fulfillment_id />
      <location_name>201 - PA</location_name>
      <manifest_number />
      <picker_name />
      <scheduled_pick_date />
      <pick_timestamp />
      <delivery_timestamp />
      <packaging_weight>0.150000</packaging_weight>
      <insured_value />
      <bill_to_zip />
      <internal_note>TESTING NOTE</internal_note>
      <bill_to_account />
      <status>shipped</status>
      <dock_number />
      <route_id>1</route_id>
      <delivery_latitude />
      <shipper_id>1</shipper_id>
      <scheduled_ship_date>07/18/2016</scheduled_ship_date>
      <acceptance_timestamp />
      <shipping_carrier />
      <packaging_height>4.0000</packaging_height>
      <packaging_length>4.0000</packaging_length>
      <gross_weight>440.15</gross_weight>
      <packaging_width>4.0000</packaging_width>
      <delivery_longitude />
      <delivery_signer_location />
      <packing_layer />
      <truck_number />
      <route_name />
      <flag_message />
      <delivery_signer_name />
      <tracking_number />
      <packing_row />
      <ship_timestamp>06/09/2016 07:15:15 AM</ship_timestamp>
   </fulfillments>
</data>
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Added sample code of what I am doing. The problem I'm having is that it will loop though all the shiptos for each fulfillment. Which is what I predicted would happen given the code. The issue is how can I maintain the parent child relationship when displaying it so that I only display the shipto info for each fulfullment and not every shipto for each fulfillment.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure if this works in 10.c or not. It certainly works in 11.6.

If you use a `PARENT-ID-RELATION` when you define the dataset a record id of the parent buffer will be added to all children when you `READ-XML`

I've added a simplified version here. You might want to change data types. The `PARENT-FIELDS-BEFORE` and `PARENT-FIELDS-AFTER` are just needed to make the output dataset look the same (basically if places the "ship_to" part in the right place). It's not needed for just reading the xml and iterating through the records.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttFulfillments NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "fulfillments"
    FIELD shipping_method          AS CHARACTER
    FIELD picker_id                AS CHARACTER
    FIELD sales_order_id           AS CHARACTER
    FIELD packaging_id             AS CHARACTER
    FIELD scheduled_delivery_date  AS CHARACTER
    FIELD net_weight               AS CHARACTER
    FIELD shipper_name             AS CHARACTER
    FIELD external_note            AS CHARACTER
    FIELD packaging_type           AS CHARACTER
    FIELD bill_to                  AS CHARACTER
    FIELD shipping_cost            AS CHARACTER
    FIELD fulfillment_id           AS CHARACTER
    FIELD location_id              AS CHARACTER
    FIELD parent_fulfillment_id    AS CHARACTER
    FIELD location_name            AS CHARACTER
    FIELD manifest_number          AS CHARACTER
    FIELD picker_name              AS CHARACTER
    FIELD scheduled_pick_date      AS CHARACTER
    FIELD pick_timestamp           AS CHARACTER
    FIELD delivery_timestamp       AS CHARACTER
    FIELD packaging_weight         AS CHARACTER
    FIELD insured_value            AS CHARACTER
    FIELD bill_to_zip              AS CHARACTER
    FIELD internal_note            AS CHARACTER
    FIELD bill_to_account          AS CHARACTER
    FIELD fullfill_status          AS CHARACTER SERIALIZE-NAME "status" 
    FIELD dock_number              AS CHARACTER
    FIELD route_id                 AS CHARACTER
    FIELD delivery_latitude        AS CHARACTER
    FIELD shipper_id               AS CHARACTER
    FIELD scheduled_ship_date      AS CHARACTER
    FIELD acceptance_timestamp     AS CHARACTER
    FIELD shipping_carrier         AS CHARACTER
    FIELD packaging_height         AS CHARACTER
    FIELD packaging_length         AS CHARACTER
    FIELD gross_weight             AS CHARACTER
    FIELD packaging_width          AS CHARACTER
    FIELD delivery_longitude       AS CHARACTER
    FIELD delivery_signer_location AS CHARACTER
    FIELD packing_layer            AS CHARACTER
    FIELD truck_number             AS CHARACTER
    FIELD route_name               AS CHARACTER
    FIELD flag_message             AS CHARACTER
    FIELD delivery_signer_name     AS CHARACTER
    FIELD tracking_number          AS CHARACTER
    FIELD packing_row              AS CHARACTER
    FIELD ship_timestamp           AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttShipTo NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "ship_to"
    FIELD parent_recid    AS RECID SERIALIZE-HIDDEN
    FIELD city            AS CHARACTER
    FIELD shipto_name     AS CHARACTER SERIALIZE-NAME "name"
    FIELD zip             AS CHARACTER
    FIELD is_residential  AS CHARACTER
    FIELD company         AS CHARACTER
    FIELD address         AS CHARACTER
    FIELD phone_extension AS CHARACTER
    FIELD contact_id      AS CHARACTER
    FIELD phone           AS CHARACTER
    FIELD state           AS CHARACTER
    FIELD country         AS CHARACTER
    FIELD email           AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE DATASET dsData SERIALIZE-NAME "data"
    FOR ttFulfillments, ttShipTo
    PARENT-ID-RELATION pr1 FOR ttFulFillments, ttShipTo 
        PARENT-ID-FIELD parent_recid
        PARENT-FIELDS-BEFORE (shipping_method, picker_id, sales_order_id, packaging_id, scheduled_deliv, net_weight, shipper_name, external_note, packaging_type, bill_to, shipping_cost, fulfillment_id )
        PARENT-FIELDS-AFTER  (location_id,parent_fulfillment_id,location_name,manifest_number,picker_name,scheduled_pick_date,pick_timestamp, delivery_timestamp, packaging_weight, insured_value, bill_to_zip, internal_note, bill_to_account, fullfill_status, dock_number, route_id, delivery_latitude, shipper_id, scheduled_ship_date, acceptance_timestamp, shipping_carrier, packaging_height, packaging_length, gross_weight, packaging_width, delivery_longitude, delivery_signer_location, packing_layer, truck_number, route_name, flag_message, delivery_signer_name, tracking_number, packing_row, ship_timestamp).

DATASET dsData:READ-XML("file", "c:\temp\sample-data.xml", "empty", ?, ?, ?, ?).

/* Output dataset just to have a reference to compare to the input... */
DATASET dsData:WRITE-XML("file","c:\temp\output-data.xml").

/* Iterate on temp-tables */
FOR EACH ttFulfillments :
    DISPLAY ttFulfillments.

    FOR EACH ttShipTo WHERE ttShipTo.parent_recid = RECID(ttFulfillments):
        DISPLAY ttShipTo EXCEPT ttShipTo.parent_recid.
    END.

END.
```

Comment: PARENT-ID-RELATION was added since 11.x

Comment: This would work but not on 10.1c. I went ahead and just manually parsed the xml for the data I needed. I was just hoping there would be a way to easily use the read-xml functionality.